# Is there any way to overwrite CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET

Tags: php, api, laravel, twitter

I am using laravel with the thujohn/twitter package.
But i want whenever any use registered  they will provide us CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET and we  will use that details  to post the tweet,favorites tweet etc.

But in the thujohn/twitter package the CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET is set one time and  that will use for all users and i want to use each register user will use their own consumer details.

Any one know any solution on the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code you have the reconfigure method:

```
/**
 * Set new config values for the OAuth class like different tokens.
 *
 * @param Array $config An array containing the values that should be overwritten.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function reconfig($config)
{
    // The consumer key and secret must always be included when reconfiguring
    $config = array_merge($this->parent_config, $config);
    parent::reconfigure($config);
    return $this;
}
```

So you can pass an array with the configs you want:

```
Twitter::reconfigure([
    'consumer_key'               => '',
    'consumer_secret'            => '',
    'token'                      => '',
    'secret'                     => '',
]);
```

This configs will then be passed to the parent which is another library called [tmhOAuth](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth) here's the code for that:

```
public function reconfigure($config=array()) {
    // default configuration options
    $this->config = array_merge(
        array(
            // leave 'user_agent' blank for default, otherwise set this to
            // something that clearly identifies your app
            'user_agent'                 => '',
            'host'                       => 'api.twitter.com',
            'method'                     => 'GET',
            'consumer_key'               => '',
            'consumer_secret'            => '',
            'token'                      => '',
            'secret'                     => '',
            // OAuth2 bearer token. This should already be URL encoded
            'bearer'                     => '',
            // oauth signing variables that are not dynamic
            'oauth_version'              => '1.0',
            'oauth_signature_method'     => 'HMAC-SHA1',
            // you probably don't want to change any of these curl values
            'curl_http_version'          => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            'curl_connecttimeout'        => 30,
            'curl_timeout'               => 10,
            // for security this should always be set to 2.
            'curl_ssl_verifyhost'        => 2,
            // for security this should always be set to true.
            'curl_ssl_verifypeer'        => true,
            // for security this should always be set to true.
            'use_ssl'                    => true,
            // you can get the latest cacert.pem from here http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
            // if you're getting HTTP 0 responses, check cacert.pem exists and is readable
            // without it curl won't be able to create an SSL connection
            'curl_cainfo'                => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cacert.pem',
            'curl_capath'                => __DIR__,
            // in some cases (very very odd ones) the SSL version must be set manually.
            // unless you know why your are changing this, you should leave it as false
            // to allow PHP to determine the value for this setting itself.
            'curl_sslversion'            => false,
            'curl_followlocation'        => false, // whether to follow redirects or not
            // support for proxy servers
            'curl_proxy'                 => false, // really you don't want to use this if you are using streaming
            'curl_proxyuserpwd'          => false, // format username:password for proxy, if required
            'curl_encoding'              => '',    // leave blank for all supported formats, else use gzip, deflate, identity etc
            // streaming API configuration
            'is_streaming'               => false,
            'streaming_eol'              => "\r\n",
            'streaming_metrics_interval' => 10,
            // header or querystring. You should always use header!
            // this is just to help me debug other developers implementations
            'as_header'                  => true,
            'force_nonce'                => false, // used for checking signatures. leave as false for auto
            'force_timestamp'            => false, // used for checking signatures. leave as false for auto
        ),
        $config
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i am trying your code and pass the consumer_key and consumer_secret but i am getting the error "[220] Your credentials do not allow access to this resource."  and same time i check the permission of  app but its proper set

Comment: Well it seems that is setting the consumer_key and the consumer_secret, are you sure that you are setting the proper values for the consumer_key, consumer, token and secret? Try activating twitter debug to check the logs https://github.com/thujohn/twitter#debug

Comment: you mean to say we have to provided token and secret of same user who  provided  his consumer_key, consumer_secret

Comment: Yes, unless you have something on your app were you request users to grant permission to your app

Comment: Fabio  Can  you tell me is there any possible way to take registered user token and secret  (who provide me consumer_key and ,consumer_secret ) on the basis of my own consumer_key and ,consumer_secret, token,consumer_key and the consumer_secret,

Comment: No, you need to something like 3 legged authentication https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/3-legged you ask users to grant permissions to your app, you then get an access token for that consumer_secret and consumer_key, so if you have 10 different consumer_keys and consumer secrets your user would have to this 3 legged authentication ten times and for each one you would get a different token.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97278/discussion-between-cms-coders-and-fabio-antunes).